# How to avoid a specific tag while extracting xpath

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xpath

By using xpath(.//div[@class="entry-content"]/div/p//text()') i am getting all the text1,text2,.....text6. How to take only "text3","text4","text5","text6"??

```
`<div class="entry-content">
   <div>
     <p>
     <st>text1</st>
     </p>
     <p>
     <st>text2</st>
     </p>
   </div>
   <p>"text3"</p>
   <div>
     <p>
     <st>"text4"</st>
     </p>
     <p>
     <st>"text5"</st>
     </p>
     <p>
     <st>"text6"</st>
     </p>
   </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: what's the logic behind the selection? is it that you want to ignore the first "div" subnode?

Comment: i need to extract the **"text3","text4","text5","text6"** by avoiding the first two `<p>` tags that containing **text1** and **text2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want nodes within the second `div`, use the path

```
.//div[@class="entry-content"]/div[2]/p//text()
```

If want nodes in all `div`s except the first, write

```
.//div[@class="entry-content"]/div[position()>1]/p//text()
```

If you want to select on some other basis, then explain what rules you want to apply. (Your question says "avoid a specific tag", but you are very *unspecific* about what tag you want to avoid).

Comment: i meant to avoid the first two <p> tags that is containing the text1 and text2

Comment: Sir, these two codes you mentioned here results the same output (output is "text4","text5", "text6"). I also needed the <p>"text3"</p>

Answer (score 0):

As per your clarification it seems that "p" are the nodes you want to avoid, in particular the first 2 of them. As they may appear at different depth level, one of the ways you achieve it is with this xpath expression, which is basically a variation of the solution provided by Michael Kay:

```
//div[@class="entry-content"]//descendant::p[position()>2]//text()
```